# Extract names around each word regex

Tags: python, regex

There is a string

```
Mary loves Mike,Jack loves Lily,Ethan loves Lydia
```

I want to extract the names around each `loves` with python.But the code below can't work.

```
names = re.search(r'(\S+) loves (\S+)',str, ) 
while names: 
    print names.group(1) 
    print names.group(2)
```

Comment: It would be helpful in the future to include the actual errors that you are seeing or if there are no errors the expected/actual outputs. This will help the community understand exactly what you are trying to do and what issues you are facing. `"Doesn't work"` is not really a good explanation :)

Comment: @professorz I notice that you thank Lix, but don't change your question to incorporate their suggested improvement - are you aware that you can make edits?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
>>> import re
>>> re.findall(r"([a-zA-Z]+) loves ([a-zA-Z]+)", "Mary loves Mike,Jack loves Lily,Ethan loves Lydia")
[('Mary', 'Mike'), ('Jack', 'Lily'), ('Ethan', 'Lydia')]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use \w+ to extract words. And also since you want to extract all the matches, you can use a find all.

```
str="Mary loves Mike,Jack loves Lily,Ethan loves Lydia";
names = re.findall("(\w+) loves (\w+)", str)
for name in  names:
        print name
```

Comment: `\w` supports underscores and numbers though, not usually in a name